# How can a function value is displayed in a HTML tag with a return value from addEventListerner click?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to build a calculator and want to print digits on the screen. I have not yet put the calculator algorithm, just only to print the digits on the screen.

```
const Keys = ({calcKeys})=>(<div className="display-keys"> 
   <div className="screen"><handleClick></div>
      {calcKeys.map((item)=>{
            return <button className="display-keys">{item.key}</button>
      })
 }
 class App extends React.Component { constructor(props) { super(props);
     this.state={calcKeys:[{"key": "AC"},{"key": "CE"},{"key": "±"},{"key": "/"},{"key": "7"},{"key": "8"},{"key": "9"},{"key": "x"},{"key": "4"},{"key": "5"},{"key": "6"},{"key": "-"},{"key": "1"},{"key": "2"},{"key": "3"},{"key": "+"},{"key": "."},{"key": "0"}]};}
      this.displayKeys = this.displayKeys.bind(this)];
      const keyButton = document.querySelector('.display-keys');
      handleClick() {
      keyButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      return const keyPad = e.key;
   });
  } 
render(){
   return(
      <div className="display-container">
       <Keys calcKeys={this.state.calcKeys}/>
      </div> 
    );
 }
}
  ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You might get a bit of help from here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-an-html-calculator-app-from-scratch-using-javascript-4454b8714b98/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case, if you want to click on the button you don't need to add an `addEventListener`.

As you are using React, you can create a function to handle click.
If you want to handle a keypress on the keyboard, that's the case to use `addEventListener`.

I changed your code a bit in order to make it work as expected. I didn't add any logic to make the calculator work but clicking on any button will add it to state and display on "screen".

This is what I did:

```
// "Keys" Component receives the calcKeys and the handleClick function.
// It uses the handleClick function on the button onClick passing the current item key
const Keys = ({ calcKeys, handleClick }) => (
  <div className="display-keys">
    {calcKeys.map(item => (
        <button onClick={() => handleClick(item.key)}>{item.key}</button>
     ))}
  </div>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      calcKeys: [{"key": "AC"},{"key": "CE"},{"key": "±"},{"key": "/"},{"key": "7"},{"key": "8"},{"key": "9"},{"key": "x"},{"key": "4"},{"key": "5"},{"key": "6"},{"key": "-"},{"key": "1"},{"key": "2"},{"key": "3"},{"key": "+"},{"key": "."},{"key": "0"}],
      value: '',
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  // Here I just receive the key and add it to state.
  // This is the place to add logic, check if the key is "AC" for example and clean the state, etc.
  handleClick(key) {
    const { value } = this.state

    this.setState({ value: `${value}${key}` })
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="display-container">
        <div className="screen">{value}</div>
        <Keys calcKeys={this.state.calcKeys} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can test it in a working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/guilhermetoti/vk85460y/10//)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: It is not printing the screen, which is my main issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I sent the wrong JSFiddle link. I've just updated the link! Or you can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/guilhermetoti/vk85460y/10/)