# Can a React function be changed into a class component

Tags: reactjs

Please check the answer in the following link by Guilherme Toti.

[How can a function value is displayed in a HTML tag with a return value from addEventListerner click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741347/how-can-a-function-value-is-displayed-in-a-html-tag-with-a-return-value-from-add)

Is it possible, if I can use "const Keys" as a react component i.e.:  "class Keys extends React.Component".

```
 const Keys = ({ calcKeys, handleClick }) => (
    <div className="display-keys">
      {calcKeys.map(item => (
           <button onClick={() => handleClick(item.key)}>{item.key}</button>
       ))}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can*, all you need to do is reference the component's props in a `render` method:

```
class Keys extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { calcKeys, handleClick } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="display-keys">
        {calcKeys.map(item => (
             <button onClick={() => handleClick(item.key)}>{item.key}</button>
         ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But it's somewhat odd to want to do - it makes the code longer without much reason, and React themselves [recommend to try using functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both) in new code when possible.

Answer (score 1):

yes. you certainly can re-write as class component. But the trend is to rewrite class components into functional.

What can be done as class component can also be achieved by the functional kind. Functional components also have the advantage of using hooks.

take a look at [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)